# How to launch this intent from the action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, location

I understand that for security reasons you can not programmatically enable/disable location services.

Thus I want to create an action bar icon that fires the ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS intent, and allows for users to do it within their own settings page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please refer to https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Answer (score 0):

a menu option something like this is super.easy() to hook into the action bar.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int x = item.getItemId();
    switch (x) {
    case R.id.action_gps:
        startActivity(new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_gps"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_gps"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_gps"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```